# Headless content implementation in Tridion 9.5

Tags: graphql, sites-9.5

We just upgraded to Tridion 9.5 and plan to implement headless content model using out of the box features of Tridion 9.5. Not able to get end-to-end implementation details in Tridion docs. I am looking for a jump start on this - from schema implementation to content delivery if anyone implemented.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange, Venkat! As an upgrade, your team might already be familiar with Schemas and perhaps the GraphQL API, but it's hard to know what you need without some background. Perhaps you're looking for an example of setting up a semantic content model or perhaps how to change an existing setup? Let us know by editing your original question, offering an example, and yes, sharing what you've tried! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackExchange. It would be great if you can provide information on what you have tried and specific implementation questions, if any. There is no cookie-cutter solution for data-only publishing. You will find a lot of useful information in [this link.](https://docs.sdl.com/816112/816516/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/templateless--data-only-publishing)

From the content manager side, the schema design is completely open to the developer / content authors / marketers. Both the schemas and the fields that needs to be published can be configured. Searching based on the fields should also be configured on the CMS side. You need to understand that schema definition (referred to as content-modelling, sometimes) is an iterative process and will get refined with your business requirements and technical complexity.

From the content delivery side, GraphQl documentation can be found under [public content API](https://docs.sdl.com/816112/805566/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/content-delivery-------------public-content-api). There are quite a few useful [examples](https://docs.sdl.com/816112/658699/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/graphql-samples) in the documentation as well.

EDIT:

Semantic content models grants the developer more control in defining a custom model for your web application independent of the default fields in DXD. Future changes in your content model won't impact your web application. I have also [linked a video](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-sites/m/videos/4287) of it for better understanding.

Comment: Don't forget the semantic content models, which might be new to some implementations! :-)

Comment: Good point, Alvin. I have linked a video from RWS community as well; :).

Answer (score 2):

Running the risk of over-simplifying...

1. Define your content models (on paper, not in Tridion).
2. Translate that to a set of Tridion Schemas that allow for the content to be captured.
3. Work on your semantic content models as mentioned by others, to further refine the mapping between your Content creation models and your Content Delivery models (i.e., how content shows on your website)
4. Create some content, put it in pages, publish.
5. Check out the output using GraphQL
6. Build an application that consumes that content (using graphql)

Done.